# Check the monotonicity of an inductive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, self-learning, monotone-functions

Given
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{\dfrac{ab^2+a_n^2}{a+1}}\,\,\forall n$$
Where $a>0, 0< a_1< b, a=a_1$

I obtained the expression for terms $a_2^2, a_3^2, a_4^2,...,a_n^2$ and do the summation of $a_i^2-a_{i-1}^2$ but that results in $a_n^2-a_2^2= \dfrac{a_{n-1}^2-a_1^2}{a+1}$, which I have no clue what to do with it further. Any little trick or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;a_{n+1}^2 = \lambda a_n^2+\mu\,$ is a linear recurrence for $\,a_n^2\,$ which you can solve and get the closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that
$$ a_2^2-a_1^2 = \frac{ab^2+a_1^2}{a+1}-a_1^2 = \frac{ab^2+a^2}{a+1}-\frac{a^2(a+1)}{a+1}= \frac{a(b^2-a^2)}{a+1}. $$
We get that $a_2^2-a_1^2$, as the right hand side is positive, and so $a_2>a_1$ (these are square roots, hence positive).

Also, note that
$$ a_{n+1}^2 - a_n^2 = \frac{ab^2+a_n^2}{a+1}-\frac{ab^2+a_{n-1}^2}{a+1} = \frac{a_n^2-a_{n-1}^2}{a+1}. $$
This way, $a_n>a_{n-1}$ implies $a_{n+1}>a_n$, and so by induction the sequence is increasing.